# If Statement to Check for Current Null Values in a Selector Overwrite?

Tags: acumatica

I am customizing the ARPaymentEntry logic so that it uses a custom field that we have on the "Invoices and Memos" screen and impacts the "Payments and Applications" screen. This required field is an extension of ARRegister and currently has only two states, A and B.

With the way the code is below, if I have a payment saved in the P&A screen with one line with an "A" record, it will only allow me to add "A" records to that payment. So if we get a line in there with an "A" or "B" value, it will only allow those values through the selector. This is the first half of what I would like to do.

If I change the code to manually set the value that it checks against to "A", the selector will only show records with that letter on the "Payments and Applications" screen, but it also only allows "A" records to come from the "Invoices and Memos" screen via the "Enter Payment Button".

What I'd like to do next is create some kind of if statement that can see if the value of Current2 Custom.DAC.ARRegisterExtension.customField is null, and if it is, do no evaluation, but if it is not null, it should evaluate against the current value. This way, the I&M screen still can pass single records over to P&A and users can select a starting document on the P&A screen from any invoice and it will restrict the user to that type after the first invoice is chosen. I've been working on if statements in this BQL query to try to get the correct result, but I have not been able to come up with the correct solution.

Please let me know if there is anything that I can clarify here, I know it was a bit long-winded...

The section that I changed was:

```
Where<Custom.DAC.ARRegisterExtension.customField, Equal<Current2<Custom.DAC.ARRegisterExtension.customField>>,
```

Here is the code:

```
using PX.Data;
using Custom.DAC;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
    {
        #region AdjdRefNbr
        protected string _AdjdRefNbr;
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reference Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        [ARInvoiceType.AdjdRefNbr(typeof(Search2<ARInvoice.refNbr,
            LeftJoin<ARAdjust, On<ARAdjust.adjdDocType, Equal<ARInvoice.docType>,
                And<ARAdjust.adjdRefNbr, Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>,
                And<ARAdjust.released, NotEqual<True>,
                And<ARAdjust.voided, NotEqual<True>,
                And<Where<ARAdjust.adjgDocType, NotEqual<Current<ARRegister.docType>>,
                    Or<ARAdjust.adjgRefNbr, NotEqual<Current<ARRegister.refNbr>>>>>>>>>,
            LeftJoin<ARAdjust2, On<ARAdjust2.adjgDocType, Equal<ARInvoice.docType>,
                And<ARAdjust2.adjgRefNbr, Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>,
                And<ARAdjust2.released, NotEqual<True>,
                And<ARAdjust2.voided, NotEqual<True>>>>>,
            LeftJoin<Customer, On<ARInvoice.customerID, Equal<Customer.bAccountID>>>>>,
            Where<Custom.DAC.ARRegisterExtension.customField, Equal<Current2<Custom.DAC.ARRegisterExtension.customField>>,
                And<ARInvoice.docType, Equal<Optional<ARAdjust.adjdDocType>>,
                And<ARInvoice.released, Equal<True>, 
                And<ARInvoice.openDoc, Equal<True>, 
                And<ARAdjust.adjgRefNbr, IsNull, 
                And<ARAdjust2.adjdRefNbr, IsNull,
                And<ARInvoice.customerID, In2<Search<Override.BAccount.bAccountID,
            Where<Override.BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Optional<ARRegister.customerID>>, 
                    Or<Override.BAccount.consolidatingBAccountID, Equal<Optional<ARRegister.customerID>>>>>>,
                And<Where<ARInvoice.pendingPPD, NotEqual<True>,
                    Or<Current<ARRegister.pendingPPD>, Equal<True>>>>>>>>>>>>), Filterable = true)]
        #endregion
        protected virtual void ARAdjust_AdjdRefNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For conditional validation you would need to do an event for field verifying (public virtual void DacName_FieldName_FieldVerifying(PXCache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs, PXFieldVerifying)) and if the condition his where you do not want to validate then set e.cancel = true to cancel the verifying. This works on the graph. If you want this to work from the DAC then create an attribute and attach it to the dac which adds the fieldverifying. Hope this helps some. In summary the selector paired with the field verifying should give you what you need if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help Brendan! I was actually able to get this to work with just an IsNotNull to exclude the null results from the selector results. I'm sorry for not being more clear in my post, thanks for your response, it helped me to get on the right track!

Comment: sounds good. Don't forget to answer your own question.